# What causes differences in PHPUnit code coverage reports for the same code basis?

Tags: php, jenkins, phpunit, code-coverage, clover

I have a PHP project with some unit and some integration tests. I deploy it with Jenkins: locally on my Ubuntu VM and on the test server on Windows Server 2008 r2.

The `build.xml`s and `phpunit.xml`s for the local VM and the test server are on the whole identical (the differences are only in slashes and how services like `phpunit` are called, s. below). But the code coverage reports display different results. Locally the code coverage is approximately `10%` higher than on the server:

**local VM (Ubuntu)**

*PHPUnit Code Coverage*: Lines 90.24%, Functions and Methods 95.31%, Classes and Traits 85.00%

[image]

*Clover PHP Coverage Report*: Code Coverage - 77% (5295/6880 elements): 77% (5295/6880 elements), Methods 79.3%, Statements 76.5%

[image]

**test server (Windows Server 2008 r2)**

*PHPUnit Code Coverage*: Lines 81.89%, Functions and Methods 85.25%, Classes and Traits 57.81%%

[image]

*Clover PHP Coverage Report*: Code Coverage - 77% (5295/6880 elements): 77% (5295/6880 elements), Methods 79.3%, Statements 76.5%

[image]

**What might cause such a difference and how to correct it?**

---

**more info**

**local `build.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="full-build">
    ...
    <property name="phpunit" value="./vendor/bin/phpunit" />
    <target name="full-build" depends="prepare,static-analysis,phpdox,phpunit,-check-failure" description="Performs static analysis, runs the tests, and generates project documentation." />
    ...
    <target name="phpunit" unless="phpunit.done" depends="prepare" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
        <exec executable="${phpunit}" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit">
            <arg value="--configuration" />
            <arg path="${basedir}/phpunit.xml" />
        </exec>
        <property name="phpunit.done" value="true" />
    </target>
    <target name="-check-failure">
        <fail message="PHPUnit did not finish successfully">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${result.phpunit}" arg2="0" />
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```

**`build.xml` on the server:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyProject" default="full-build">
    ...
    <property name="phpunit" value="vendor\phpunit\phpunit\phpunit" />
    <target name="full-build" depends="prepare,static-analysis,phpdox,phpunit,-check-failure" description="Performs static analysis, runs the tests, and generates project documentation." />
    ...
    <target name="phpunit" unless="phpunit.done" depends="prepare" description="Run unit tests with PHPUnit">
        <exec executable="cmd" resultproperty="result.phpunit" taskname="phpunit">
            <arg value="/c" />
            <arg value="phpdbg" />
            <arg value="-qrr" />
            <arg value="${phpunit}" />
            <arg value="--configuration" />
            <arg path="${basedir}/phpunit.xml" />
        </exec>
        <property name="phpunit.done" value="true" />
    </target>
    <target name="-check-failure">
        <fail message="PHPUnit did not finish successfully">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <equals arg1="${result.phpunit}" arg2="0" />
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```

**local `phpunit.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="test/Bootstrap.php"
     cacheTokens="false"
     colors="true"
>
    <php>
        <env name="RUNTIME_CONTEXT" value="testing"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit-app-only">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration-app-only">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test/Integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="app-lib">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">vendor/my-lib/mlb-common-lib/tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build/coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/logs/clover.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="build/logs/crap4j.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build/logs/junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">module/**/src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor/my-lib/**/src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">vendor/my-lib/**/tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

**`phpunit.xml` on the server:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.1/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     bootstrap="test/Bootstrap.php"
     cacheTokens="false"
     colors="true"
>
    <php>
        <env name="RUNTIME_CONTEXT" value="testing"/>
    </php>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit-app-only">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test\Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration-app-only">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">test\Integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="app-lib">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">vendor\my-lib\mlb-common-lib\tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="build\coverage"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="build\logs\clover.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-crap4j" target="build\logs\crap4j.xml"/>
        <log type="junit" target="build\logs\junit.xml" logIncompleteSkipped="false"/>
    </logging>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">module\**\src</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">vendor\my-lib\**\src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".php">vendor\my-lib\**\tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

---

**UPDATE**

Software versions:

**local Ubuntu VM**

- PHP `7.0.3`
- Xdebug `2.4.0RC4`
- PHPUnit `6.2.2`

**Windows 2008 server**

- PHP `7.0.2`
- PHPUnit `6.2.2`

Comment: Which version of PHP, PHPUnit, Xdebug, etc. do you use?

Comment: Could it be that your code runs in a different environment, e.g. dev vs. prod, or with different settings and that changes the code paths in your integration tests?

Comment: @SebastianBergmann The local Ubuntu VM: PHP `7.0.3`, Xdebug `2.4.0RC4`, PHPUnit `6.2.2`. The Windows 2008 server: PHP `7.0.2`, PHPUnit `6.2.2`.

Comment: @dbrumann I checked all configs, that might be relevant. I don't know whether I forgot something. Is there anything, that might make a difference and is not in my question (in the sections `build.xml` and `phpunit.xml`)?

Comment: Only if you have a custom application config that differs on both systems. For example `parameters.yml` in Symfony or something like a `.env` file. For example if you disable mailing on the server, it might not run this part of the code, both in your app and in the vendor folder. Have you compared the logs? Maybe your server runs into exceptions that are caught and for some reason don't fail the tests but make it skip part of the code? Some of your dependencies may run different code based on OS (check e.g. `uname()` or `PHP_OS` usage), but that shouldn't cause such a noticeable difference.